# How to add ScrollBar on Textarea or JFrame in Java Swing?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, graphics, textarea

**Hi everyone ,i`m beginner in programmation and i wanted to make a text editor interface by using java Eclipse and i get problem each time i add scrollbar , the text area disappear ... How can i fix my code to continue on it ?... i saw many tutorials but nothing work**>

```
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.color.*;
    import javax.swing.*;


    public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

         JMenuBar Menubar  = new JMenuBar();
         JMenu MenuFichier = new JMenu("Fichier");
         JMenuItem MenuFichier1 = new JMenuItem("Nouveau");
         JMenuItem MenuFichier2 = new JMenuItem("Ouvrir");
         JMenuItem MenuFichier3 = new JMenuItem("Enregister");
         JMenuItem MenuFichier4 = new JMenuItem("Enregister sous");
         JMenuItem MenuFichier5 = new JMenuItem("Quitter");

         JMenu MenuEdition = new JMenu("Edition");
         JMenuItem MenuEdition1 = new JMenuItem("Couper");
         JMenuItem MenuEdition2 = new JMenuItem("Copier");
         JMenuItem MenuEdition3 = new JMenuItem("Coller");

         JMenu MenuAide = new JMenu("Aide");
         JMenuItem MenuAide1 = new JMenuItem("A propos");

         JPanel p=new JPanel();

         JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane ();
         JTextArea jt = new JTextArea (90,90);

        public Fenetre() {

        add(p);
        setTitle("Text Editor");
        setBounds(100,100, 500, 500);
        //setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        sp.add(jt);
        jt.setText(null);
        jt.setLineWrap(true);
        jt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jt.setVisible(true);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        p.add(sp);
        sp.setVisible(true);

        Menubar.add(MenuFichier);
        Menubar.add(MenuEdition);
        Menubar.add(MenuAide);

        MenuFichier.add(MenuFichier1);
        MenuFichier.add(MenuFichier2);
        MenuFichier.addSeparator();

        MenuFichier.add(MenuFichier3);
        MenuFichier.add(MenuFichier4);
        MenuFichier.addSeparator();
        MenuFichier.add(MenuFichier5);

        MenuEdition.add(MenuEdition1);
        MenuEdition.add(MenuEdition2);

        MenuAide.add(MenuAide1);
        Menubar.setBackground(Color.PINK);


        getContentPane().add(sp);
        setJMenuBar(Menubar);
        setVisible(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




    }}
```

and this is the main of the code 
    import java.awt.*;

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.Color;

    public class CreationEditor {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
             JFrame f = new Fenetre(); 



    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't add the component to the JScrollPane as you're doing as that replaces the scroll pane's viewport. Instead either pass the component in via the JScrollPane constructor, which indirectly adds the component to the viewport (which is what you want) or directly add the component to the viewport via `myJScrollPane.setViewportView(myComponent)`

Comment: i tried an other method just right now and it works , but now i didn`t know how to add ToolBar int the south of my page !

Comment: To add a toolbar to the jframe, use layout like BorderLayout